# Python O365 send email with HTML file

Tags: python, html, email, office365

I'm using O365 for Python. 
Sending an email and building the body my using the setBodyHTML() function. However at the present I need to write the actual HTML code inside the function. I don't want to do that. I want to just have python look at an HTML file I saved somewhere and send an email using that file as the body. Is that possible? Or am I confined to copy/pasting my HTML into that function?  I'm using office365 for business. Thanks.

In other words instead of this: `msg.setBodyHTML("<h3>Hello</h3>")` I want to be able to do this: `msg.setBodyHTML("C:\somemsg.html")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can assign the file content to a variable first, i.e.:

```
file = open('C:/somemsg.html', 'r')
content = file.read()
file.close()
msg.setBodyHTML(content)
```

Comment: Excellent. This worked. Now I should ask if there is a way to implement CSS into this HTML of mine but not sure if I need a new thread for that as it may be off topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a simple reading of that file into a string, which you then can pass to the `setBodyHTML` function.

Here's a quick function example that will do the trick:

```
def load_html_from_file(path):
    contents = ""
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read()

    return contents
```

Later, you can do something along the lines of

```
msg.setBodyHTML(load_html_from_file("C:\somemsg.html"))
```

or
`html_contents = load_html_from_file("C:\somemsg.html")
    msg.setBodyHTML(html_contents)`